# Proving statements with "finite sum property"

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B \subset R$ be a set of positive real numbers with the following "finite sum property":
adding finitely many elements of $B$ gives a sum of 1 or less. Prove the following statements:
(a) For all $\epsilon > 0$ , there exists only finitely many $x \in B$ with $x > \epsilon$

(b) $B \cup \{0\}$ is compact

This is what I did for (a):
I need to show that there exists at least one $x<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.
Let $\epsilon=1$, if all $x>1$ then $x_1+x_2+x_3 \dots x_n > n.1 > 1$ (contradiction). Is this correct?

For (b) I don't have a clue. Any hint is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: (a) Showing that there exists at least one $x < \epsilon$ does *not* imply that there are only finitely many $x > \epsilon$.

Comment: Assume that for some $\epsilon>0$ there are infinitely many $x>\epsilon$. How big can you then make a sum out of finitely many elements?

Comment: thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I'm afraid the answer to (a) is incorrect. There are good ideas in there, but the details don't work. I'll break it down:

> I need to show that there exists at least one $x<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

That isn't what you need to show, and in fact, it isn't necessarily true. Consider the case of $B=\{2/3\}$ and $\epsilon=1/3$. Clearly $B$ has the finite sum property, but there is **no** $x\in B$ with $x<1/3$.

> Let $\epsilon=1$

You want to verify a statement that is true for all $\epsilon>0$. So you're not "allowed" to choose a value for $\epsilon$. (Doing so means the rest of your argument doesn't necessarily apply to other values of $\epsilon$, which is what you want.)

> if all $x>1$

But there's no particular reason to consider the case where all $x>1$.

> then $x_1+x_2+x_3...x_n> n\cdot1 >1$ (contradiction).

What is $n$ here? Does $n$ have to be large? Remember that $B$ might have only one element, like $B=\{2/3\}$. Or $B$ might even be the empty set! So you may not be able to choose an $x_1$, let alone $n$ different members of $B$.

For a successful proof by contradiction, you should assume the *negation* of the claim that you want to prove. In this case, you want to prove the statement "For all $\epsilon > 0$ , there exists only finitely many $x \in B$ with $x > \epsilon$". The negation is: "For **some** $\epsilon > 0$ , there exists **infinitely** many $x \in B$ with $x > \epsilon$". So try assuming that and reaching a contradiction.

And if, at some point, you need to choose a large $n$, you can say that because $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $n$ such that $n\cdot\epsilon>1$, by the Archimedean property of the real numbers.

Comment: Thank you! I see the flaw now. I have one more question, does "adding finitely many elements" mean ANY finite number? Let n=number of elements and n can be 10, 5000, 4000000, 1000000000 etc?

Comment: Yep! That's right.

Comment: @LiVoonLoke Is this answer acceptable for you? If so then you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints for b):

- Can the set $B$ be unbounded?
- If $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $B \cup \{0\}$ that converges to some real number $b \in \mathbb{R}$, try to take the infinite sum of all the elements in $\{ b_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Does this sum converge? What do you know about the limit of a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ if $\sum_{n =1}^\infty a_n$ converges?